# Linux Kernal Swap?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, redhat, virtualbox, oel

I'm trying to accomplish something that's a bit outside of my comfort area, and after asking around and googling without success I thought I'd try here.

I'm trying to import a Linux VirtualBox VM into AWS. The issue is that the AWS import routine doesn’t like Oracle Enterprise/Unbreakable Linux (which the VirtualBox images that I'm in receipt of are built on). According to a [blog post](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vm-import-export-for-linux/) there are 4 supported distributions and Oracle Linux isn’t one of them (however RedHat, which Oracle Linux is based upon, is on the list). I am hopeful that swapping to RedHat would solve the issue.

I’ve found a [blog post](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/09/obiee-sampleapp-in-the-cloud-importing-virtualbox-machines-to-aws-ec2/) showing how to swap the kernel in the grub bootloader (this is their picture, not mine):

[image]

However I’m straying outside of my area of expertise here. I can vi the file, however (unlike the image above) the only listing is Oracle Linux, there are no entries for Red Hat etc. that I can swap to.

The question that I need a bit of help with is how do I get extra entries into grub.conf? I’m assuming that I need to load the RedHat kernel and then point to it here. Is that right?

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you created an HVM instance you shouldn't need to do anything special to boot the system.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I don't even get to the point of being able to boot however. The 'ec2-import-instance' command fails with 'ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 2.6.39-400.215.10.el5uek'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install package named 'kernel':

```
yum install kernel
```

In Oracle UEK, there are 3 types of kernel packages available:

- kernel
- kernel-transition
- kernel-uek

Kernel obviously is RedHat Compatible Kernel (RHCK), transition package enables you to move dependencies from RHCK to Oracle kernel, and kernel-uek is actual Oracle kernel.

Installing the package will, if successful, bring grub entries.

Comment: # yum install kernal  
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, security  
Setting up Install Process  
No package kernal available.  
Nothing to do  
#  
  
I've checked that I have internet access.

Comment: You should check your spelling of `kernel`.

Comment: <Blushes> ... that's just because I retyped it as c+p won't work from the VirtualBox window. The result is the same with kernel spelt correctly.

Comment: can you edit your post with the output of rpm -qa kernel\*

Comment: It lists 3:  
kernel-uek-2.6.39-400.215.10.el5uek  
kernel-uek-firmware-2.6.39.400.215.10.el5uek  
kernel-uek-headers-2.6.39.400.215.10.el5uek

Comment: Did this work?  I have this issue as well with an Oracle VM, and have only a single grub entry, and "yum install kernel" yields nothing.

Comment: Ok  in order to get the kernel pkg to show I needed to add the oracle repo: http://public-yum.oracle.com/getting-started.html